# How to change circle colour only when cursor hover it, not when cursor enters the frame?

Tags: swiftui, onhover

I want the following `circle` to change colour only when cursor hover over it. But it unnecessarily changes colour once it enters the `frame`. How to solve that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var snapCircleHover: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(snapCircleHover ? .yellow : .green)
               .position(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) )
                .onHover { Bool in
                    
                    if Bool {
                        snapCircleHover = true
                    } else {
                        snapCircleHover = false
                    }
                }
                .background(.black)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the circle colour **only** when cursor hover over it, after `.onHover{..}`, add:

```
.contentShape(Circle())
```

Comment: Thank you. It's weird how swiftui works. I even noticed if you put that just after the circle, swiftui throws errors. The position you place the `.contentShape(Circle()) ` is also matters. Wonder if the swiftUI documentation has mentioned it somewhere about all these things like "this should not be placed just after circle etc"